# Database Connection Error during project transfer

Tags: mysql, enterprise-architect

I have set up my MySQL repository, created tables and registred odbc driver on the client machine.

When I try to transfer project after all the configuration and clicking "Transfer" button I get popup asking for password only and then "Database Connection Error" dialog with single "Quit" button. Then all Enterprise Architect crashes.

I tried connecting to repository with project selection dialog, and it connects successfully, recognizes that there is no project and ask if I want to transfer base project to repository, so I think that connection is defined correctly.

Question: how to solve or diagnose problem cause?

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: How to solve or diagnose problem cause.

Comment: @Krever _"How to solve or diagnose problem cause."_ That's not really making an improvement of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue by following these steps:

1. Connect to local mysql instance and transfer project
2. Transfer schema to remote instance
3. Connect to remnote instance.

Moreover, I think important is to keep driver settings and EA settings consistent(user and catalog).

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a database connection problem. Make sure that you are using the correct ODBC drivers EA only wants to connect to a 32 bit ODBC connection.